# re-Install grub in ubuntu partition

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows, easybcd

I had been using Easybcd in windows to manage the bootloader. But, when i resized my ubuntu partition, grub went haywire and now I am stuck with using grub at the mbr level(i had to use boot repair to make it work).Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repair the windows bootloader and to make grub2 as default bootloader try the below steps,

- Boot *windows installation disk* then select the "*windows repair*" or "*repair your computer*" option before you go into the installation process.
- After selecting windows repair option,it will take you to the next screen.In that screen select the "command prompt" option
- Then run the below commands,on it.

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /rebuildbcd
  ```
- This will repair your windows bootloader.
- Atlast boot [*boot-repair-disk*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and click on the *recommended repair* option.Now it works.

Comment: no...I want the windows bootloader atthe mbr level and the grub in ubuntu's partition like it use to be.

Comment: by doing this first grub was displayed on the startup.From that you can choose windows or ubuntu.Grub at the mbr level will be removed.

Comment: will be removed from mbr??(no, i know that won't happen)

Comment: What I want is the windows bootloader to get control first(instead of grub.)

Comment: to make windows bootloader as default,then exclude the last step in my answer,then use easybcd to make entry for both windows and ubuntu.